# how to force to show iOS Green CallKit Bar

Tags: ios, voip, callkit

Firstly, I must explain this, I know this green bar appears if your app has support for CallKit and user went to background state from app, And these all works perfectly from my VOIP app.

But I want to implement something like Whatsapp iOS App which user can go to back instant message screen from a voice call and even client is in the active state, a green bar appears.

I do not know how WhatsApp has implemented this feature. But I guess it can be custom view (green bar when the app is in an active state but not in call screen).

Do you guys have any idea how can I implement this feature? Or Do the CallKit has any methods or something else to force to show green bar if the call screen is not appearing but also app is not in background state??

Comment: ok finally I found out, WhatsApp's green bar is not a native green bar. They made custom view as same as native green bar

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put your colored bar at the top? I am not sure if your app is using navigation controllers, but if not you should be able to align a `UIView` between `superview.top` and `safearea.top`, and set it's `backgroundColor` to anything you want.

Comment: My app has navigation controller's. I just wondered if is it any possible solution to show native green colored view while in active state like Whatsapp? I guess Whatsapp made this solution with coloredBar at the top...